# Как передать несколько значений в kendoMultiselect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ui, kendo

Есть вот такая разметка:

```
<select name="@column.ColumnName" class="detail-reference special" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select from list" data-bind="value: gridSelectedItem.Links.@column.ColumnName" required="@column.IsRequired">
@foreach (var option in column.Link.Items)
{
     <option value="@option.Id">@option.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

Здесь в `column.Link.Items` хранятся все нужные мне значения (Name, Amount, Period и т.д.). Я прохожу по всей коллекции и помещаю в `<option>` имена (Name).

Далее в скриптах инициализирую данный мультиселект:

```
var ms = $(".detail-reference").kendoMultiSelect({
                valuePrimitive: true,
                deselect: onDeselect,
                select: onSelect,
                change: onChange,
                dataTextField: "Name",
                itemTemplate: '<div class="ui-link-inherit"><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong>#: Name #</strong></p>' + '<span>Period:#: ValidFrom # - #: ValidTo #</span><p/>' + '<span>Quantity:#: Quantity #</span><p/>' + '<span>Amount:#: Amount #</span><p/>' + '<span>MenovoId:#: data.menovoId #</span></div>',
                dataValueField: "Id",
                filter: "contains",
                value: [],
                placeholder: '@T("Validation.SelectList")',
                dataSource: {
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Amount: { type: "string" },
                                MenovoId: { type: "string" },
                                Name: { type: "string" },
                                Quantity: { type: "string" },
                                RechargedValue: { type: "string" },
                                ValidFrom: { type: "string" },
                                ValidTo: { type: "string" },
                                Id: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

В итоге на выходе я получаю вот такой мультиселект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на изображении мне приходит только поле Name (и Id, но оно не нужно для отображения). Остальные поля `undefined`.

Вопрос: как мне передать и отобразить все остальные поля?

Comment: А почему не хотите спросить на форуме Kendo UI http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui/multi-select